# PHP Keep parent class properties when using a child class constructor

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I have a parent class `Database` as below

```
class Database{

    /** @var Object Filemaker object across the application*/
    protected $fm = null;
    public function __construct(){

        if($this->fm == null){
            $this->_openConnection();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to open connection to FileMaker
     * @return null
     */
    private function _openConnection(){
        $this->fm = new FileMaker();
    }
}
```

and one of my child class is

```
class Login extends Database{

    public function validate(){
        // $this->fm is accessed here with no constructors
        print_r($this->fm);
    }
}
```

I'm creating object by,

```
$login = new Login();
$login->validate();
```

Note that in this Login class, I don't have any constructor. So at the line `$login = new Login();` it is calling the Database class constructor and it calls the _openConnection(). This is fine

This is my another child class:

```
class PouleManipulation extends Database{
    private $year;
    public function __construct(){
        // $this->fm is only accessed if I call parent class constructor
        parent::__construct(); 
        $year = '2015';
    }

    public function processQueue(){
        $this->fm->perform();
    }
}
```

and

```
$pm = new PouleManipulation();
$pm->processQueue();
```

Now, when I call the `$pm = new PouleManipulation();`, note that I have a constructor for this class. If I access `$this->fm`, then it is throwing an undefined error. I googled and found that,

> Inside this class constructor I need to use `parent::__construct();` to access the parent class properties. If I didn't use `parent::__construct();` then the parent class object is not accessible when you are having a constructor in child class

Now, the problem is in the Database class $fm is null and it again calls the _openConnection(). I have totally 10 classes extending Database class and whichever classes having the constructor it calls the `_openConnection()`.

I need the $this->fm to be accessed across all the child classes with calling the `_openConnection()` only one first time and need the $this->fm in all classes well. how do you achieve this?

Comment: won't making fm static help?

Comment: `Login` *is not* __a__ `Database`. It has no business `extending` it. Learn about Dependency Injection. Instantiate one `Database` once, and pass it to all classes that need a database connection.

Comment: @deceze can you explain little more briefly? and There's no issue with visibility here. and I had some more methods inside the `Login` class as well

Comment: @deceze then I guess I didn't understand the question. However telling someone "Learn dependency injection" doesn't solve the problem (as much as I agree with you).

Comment: @ash I want to learn the issues with this and to know how to overcome this as well. "Learn dependency injection" doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks. I'll try this

Answer (score 2):

Let's clarify a bit. The properties are set on an object level. This means that everytime you instantiate a class creating an object, this object is new and has its own properties different from the others you instantiated (they may have the same value, but they're stored in different places and they're independent).

Example:

```
class Database {
    public $fm = "Value";
}

class Login extends Database {}

class PouleManipulation extends Database {}


$a = new Login();
$b = new PouleManipulation();
$b->fm = "New Value";
echo $a->fm; // prints "Value"
echo $b->fm; // prints "New Value"
```

What you're looking for is a static property, which is set at a class level. It's better if you access it through a static method. Here's a quick and dirty example, but you'd better use getters and setters.

```
class Database {
    public static $fm = "Value";
}

class Login extends Database {}

class PouleManipulation extends Database {}

$a = new Login();
$b = new PouleManipulation();
$b::$fm = "New Value";
echo $a::$fm; // prints "New Value"
echo $b::$fm; // prints "New Value"
```

**Edit:**
I used the code you provided to explain how to achieve what you want, but I want to highlight what Ryan Vincent wrote in a comment: `Login` class should use (not extend) a `Database` class

Comment: Agai `$b::$fm = "New Value";`. why?

Comment: It's an example to show that if you're gonna use a static property in the parent class, it's unique across all the objects of classes inheriting from the same parent class.